# Attempted upgrade to 19.04 FROM 19.04 failed

Tags: upgrade, intel, 19.04

I'm a bit confused. I upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04 about two weeks ago without problems. Today I was prompted with a message telling me that an upgrade to 19.04 was available and whether I wanted to install it. I agreed and the upgrade process began. I then got two error messages: that 'install-info' couldn't be installed, and then that the upgrades couldn't be installed and that the system was in a potentially unusable state (see screenshots).

I am now using the system and it appears to be fine. How can I make sure that everything is in order?

[Screenshot of the first error message I got: Could not install 'install-info'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogshy.jpg)

[Screenshot of the first error message I got: Could not install upgrades. The system could be in an unusable state.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv4ww.jpg)

edit: this is the output from `apt list systemd`

```
`$ apt list systemd
Listing... Done
systemd/disco,now 240-6ubuntu5 amd64 [installed]
systemd/disco 240-6ubuntu5 i386`


I'm using a laptop with **Intel i5** chipset.

edit2: I learned that the chipset has nothing to do with the problem. Following the output for `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` - I had to change all instances of http or https to *http because my user level is not high enough to paste that many links

`$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 *ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 *ttps://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 *ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
Hit:4 *ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Hit:5 *ttps://download.jitsi.org stable/ InRelease   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
10 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  curl gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 libcurl3-gnutls
  libcurl4 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
10 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 17.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 15.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 *ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk all 1:19.04.16.5 [9,364 B]
Get:2 *ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core all 1:19.04.16.5 [23.7 kB]
Get:3 *ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 python3-distupgrade all 1:19.04.16.5 [101 kB]
Get:4 *ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/main amd64 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 amd64 2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 [11.3 MB]
Get:5 *ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/main amd64 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 amd64 2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 [4,770 kB]
Get:6 *ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/main amd64 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 amd64 2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 [68.4 kB]
Get:7 *ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/main amd64 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 amd64 2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 [21.8 kB]
Get:8 *ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/main amd64 curl amd64 7.64.0-2ubuntu1.1 [166 kB]
Get:9 *ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/main amd64 libcurl4 amd64 7.64.0-2ubuntu1.1 [233 kB]
Get:10 *ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/main amd64 libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.64.0-2ubuntu1.1 [230 kB]
Fetched 17.0 MB in 31s (546 kB/s)                                              
(Reading database ... 271096 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1) over (2.24.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18_2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1) over (2.24.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../2-gir1.2-webkit2-4.0_2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1) over (2.24.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0_2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1) over (2.24.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk_1%3a19.04.16.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (1:19.04.16.5) over (1:19.04.16.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../5-ubuntu-release-upgrader-core_1%3a19.04.16.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:19.04.16.5) over (1:19.04.16.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../6-python3-distupgrade_1%3a19.04.16.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-distupgrade (1:19.04.16.5) over (1:19.04.16.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../7-curl_7.64.0-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.64.0-2ubuntu1.1) over (7.64.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../8-libcurl4_7.64.0-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl4:amd64 (7.64.0-2ubuntu1.1) over (7.64.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../9-libcurl3-gnutls_7.64.0-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.64.0-2ubuntu1.1) over (7.64.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up jitsi-meet-prosody (1.0.3387-1) ...
The given hostname does not exist in the config
dpkg: error processing package jitsi-meet-prosody (--configure):
 installed jitsi-meet-prosody package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.64.0-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1) ...
Setting up python3-distupgrade (1:19.04.16.5) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:19.04.16.5) ...
Setting up libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of jitsi-meet:
 jitsi-meet depends on jitsi-meet-prosody (= 1.0.3387-1); however:
  Package jitsi-meet-prosody is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package jitsi-meet (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libcurl4:amd64 (7.64.0-2ubuntu1.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Setting up curl (7.64.0-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (1:19.04.16.5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jitsi-meet-prosody
 jitsi-meet
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 *ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Hit:2 *ttps://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 *ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                         
Hit:4 *ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                 
Hit:5 *ttps://download.jitsi.org stable/ InRelease  
Reading package lists... Done                       
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up jitsi-meet-prosody (1.0.3387-1) ...
The given hostname does not exist in the config
dpkg: error processing package jitsi-meet-prosody (--configure):
 installed jitsi-meet-prosody package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of jitsi-meet:
 jitsi-meet depends on jitsi-meet-prosody (= 1.0.3387-1); however:
  Package jitsi-meet-prosody is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package jitsi-meet (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 jitsi-meet-prosody
 jitsi-meet
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

Sorry for the formatting, I'm using backticks but it doesn't appear to work

**edit3:** Okay, I finally found out how to at least get rid of the error message *System Program Problem Detected* every time I rebooted. I thought this meant that the error appeared every single time again, but a quick look to /var/crash/ made me realise that these were the previous errors (indeed from installing jitsi and the install-info error)

`ls -l /var/crash/`

I then deleted the crash reports with `sudo rm /var/crash/*` as suggested here: https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-system-program-problem-detected-ubuntu/

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Open a terminal. Please edit your question to include the complete output of the following command: `apt list systemd`

Comment: @user535733 I don't know if you can see the edit in the main post, so here it is:


`$ apt list systemd
Listing... Done
systemd/disco,now 240-6ubuntu5 amd64 [installed]
systemd/disco 240-6ubuntu5 i386`


I'm using a laptop with Intel i5 chipset.

Comment: Thank you. Now open a teminal and run `sudo apt update`, then run `sudo apt upgrade`. The output may be a bit long - add the entire output to your question.

Comment: @user535733 thank you so much for your help! I've added the output to the question. I had to change the links from http and https to *ttp because my user level doesn't allow me to post more than 10 links in one post.

Comment: Look carefully at your output: The jitsi-meet-prosody package fails, but everything else works fine. You can contact Jitsi support with that output to see if they can fix it, or you can uninstall the package and remove the Jitsi repository. Your choice.

Comment: I've removed jitsi, but I'm not sure that was the problem because I had not installed it yet when the upgrade failed. I'll see if this changes something. Thank you!